# Unity trying to convert a variable defined as a float to a vetcor3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity doesn't seem to like the way I'm declaring my variables, I was just trying to clean up my code and moved some of the variables and now it doesn't work.

The Error:

Assets\Movement.cs(33,22): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'float'

Assets\Movement.cs(39,29): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Assets\Movement.cs(41,29): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Assets\Movement.cs(43,29): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform Player;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public Text StaminaBar;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 move;
    Vector3 velocity;

    float WalkingSpeed = 12;
    float SprintingSpeed = 15;
    float CrouchingSpeed = 6;
    float gravity = 30;

    void Update(){
        Speed();
        Jump();
        Crouching();
        //Gravity
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void Speed(){
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float CurrentX = Player.transform.position.x;
        float CurrentZ = Player.transform.position.z;
        float move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        bool isWalking = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
        bool isCrouching = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
        bool isSprinting = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R);
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        if (isWalking){
            controller.Move(move * WalkingSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        } else if (isCrouching){
            controller.Move(move * CrouchingSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }else if(isSprinting){
            controller.Move(move * SprintingSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    void Jump(){
        bool isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, 0.1f, groundMask);
        
    }
    void Crouching(){
    }
    void Sliding(){
    }
    void Climbing(){
    }
    void WallRunning(){
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly in `c#`

Comment: @derHugo my bad, I don't use this site that much, no need to cry about it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring your variable `move` multiple times.

`float move = ...` should be `move = ...`

Comment: i just noticed that too, I'm a moron XD